# Postfix - mynetworks listing options

Tags: postfix

I am setting up Postfix to relay mail for our internal devices that do not support authentication.  We will have a number of devices.  Is there an easier way to list out devices vs. just listing them separated by a comma?  This list may become rather long over time with different subnets.  Any suggestions on how to better manage this list would be helpful.

```
mynetworks = 192.168.1.5, 192.168.1.62, 192.168.1.64
```

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, the easiest way might be to simply list the entire ranges, for example all the IP's you given are RFC1918 (non routable) space, so you could get away with something like

mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 
(If you are unfamiliar with it, the /XX at the end of each IP range tells how big the range is - /24 is a class C)

If you only have IP addresses in those ranges, ie you could have a host as 192.168.1.3 another as 192.168.20.44 and both would be covered as they are part of the bigger non-routed block.  (Just don't do this with IP addresses which are routable).

Another way to make life easier might be to use a hash table, mysql table or regex list (as you might do for other options) to put this information into a separately parsed file.  See [DATABASE_README.html#types](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types) for a list of lookup table types

Comment: I forgot about using a hash table.  I'll need to refresh my memory :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I created a file called auth_mailers:

```
#HQ Wired
172.16.2.2   any_value

#HQ Wireless
172.16.3.2   any_value
```

Created the hash table:

```
postmap auth_mailers
```

Edited my main.cf

```
mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/auth_mailers
```

Reloaded Postfix:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

This seems to work, but I will do more testing.

Comment: Why would you use hash-style for networks, instead of the special cidr-type?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use network notations with mask values like 192.168.0.0/16 you should use the cidr type instead of the hash one. The format is the same

```
192.168.0.0/16          any_value
10.0.0.0/8              any_value
```

Comment: davidgo's answer already suggested using CIDR notation. I don't see that this answer adds any additional information.

Comment: the original question was trying to avoid a comma separated list (davidgo suggestion) and, although Mikhail T. has suggested this on his comment having the syntax explained might help others (like me) to find a quick answer to this problem.